# change default windows file explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Hi when we use Win+E we can open windows file explorer, is there a way to use those key to change it using third party file explorer instead using windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to run another program than Explorer,
you could use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
#e::Run, "C:\path\to\exe"
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at:
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to learn how to use it.